# Error: This is not a valid schema generated by the SQL Schema Wizard

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I successfully created a Schema using the SQL Transport Schema Generation Wizard and tried to configure the Receive Location on the BizTalk Server 2006 Administration Console and i'm getting always the same error:

> Error: This is not a valid schema generated by the SQL Schema
>   Wizard

This has given me a lot of headaches and i have invested quite a bit of time and i can rule out the following causes:

- The database doesn't contain columns with unsupported types (varbinary(MAX), varchar(MAX), nvarchar(MAX), xml)
- I removed the XMLDATA at the end of the stored procedure after creating the schema
- The DLL containing the schema definition is currently deployed in the GAC
- The connection user has the corresponding permissions to execute the stored procedure

I'm running out of ideas and happy to get some help.

Comment: Have you SET NOCOUNT ON in your stored procedure?  Why are you using the old deprecated SQL adapter rather than the LOB WCF SQL adapter?